# Deploy Rails app into Heroku with Docker using heroku.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, heroku, dockerfile

After following the tutorial at: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml it was not clear which contents we should put in the `Dockerfile`.

For a Rails app what do we need in our Dockerfile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Rails 5 example that you can base your solution: https://github.com/jahangiranwari/rails5-docker-heroku/

For a Rails 6 project I've used the following **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM ruby:2.6.6

# Install node & yarn
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y yarn

# Install base deps or additional (e.g. tesseract)
ARG INSTALL_DEPENDENCIES
RUN apt-get update -qq \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ${INSTALL_DEPENDENCIES} \
    build-essential libpq-dev git \
  && apt-get clean autoclean \
  && apt-get autoremove -y \
  && rm -rf \
    /var/lib/apt \
    /var/lib/dpkg \
    /var/lib/cache \
    /var/lib/log

# Install deps with bundler
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY Gemfile* /app/
ARG BUNDLE_INSTALL_ARGS
RUN gem install bundler:2.1.4
RUN bundle config set without 'development test'
RUN bundle install ${BUNDLE_INSTALL_ARGS} \
  && rm -rf /usr/local/bundle/cache/* \
  && find /usr/local/bundle/gems/ -name "*.c" -delete \
  && find /usr/local/bundle/gems/ -name "*.o" -delete
COPY . /app/

# Compile assets
ARG RAILS_ENV=development
RUN if [ "$RAILS_ENV" = "production" ]; then SECRET_KEY_BASE=$(rake secret) bundle exec rake assets:precompile; fi
```

And this **heroku.yml** file:

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
  config:
    BUNDLE_INSTALL_ARGS: --jobs 10 --retry=3
    RAILS_ENV: production
    # Put extra deps here
    INSTALL_DEPENDENCIES: curl openssh-server python
run:
  web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

**Update 20-1-22**:
It works for Rails 7

Comment: Thanks, will this going to work with rails 7?

Comment: Haven't updated this app to Rails 7, but it should work. I'll update the answer once I do it.

Comment: @Petran I confirmed it works with Rails 7